# Set theory: fixed points of $n \mapsto \varepsilon_n$ and $n \mapsto \omega_n$

Tags: set-theory, ordinal-numbers

For an ordinal number $\alpha$, the epsilon number $\varepsilon_\alpha$ is defined as the "$\alpha$-th" fixed point of the map $n \mapsto \omega^n$, i.e. $\omega^{\varepsilon_\alpha} = \varepsilon_\alpha$.

Question: What about fixed points of $n \mapsto \varepsilon_n$ or $n \mapsto \omega_n$? Examples for the former would be $\varepsilon_{\varepsilon_{\varepsilon_{\dots}}}$ and (if I'm not mistaken) all $\omega_\alpha$ for $\alpha\ge 1$, and an example for the latter would be $\omega_{\omega_{\omega_{\dots}}}$. Do they have names? Are they studied? Do they have interesting properties?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veblen_function

Comment: General piece of advice. Don't use $n$ if your indices go beyond the natural numbers and you haven't used all the other letters in the English and Greek alphabet yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The least fixed point of $\mu \mapsto \varepsilon_\mu$ is called $\zeta_0$ and is written as $\varphi_2(0)$ using the Veblen $\varphi$ function. It is also equal to $\psi(\Omega)$ in Madore's psi function and $\psi_0(\psi_1(\psi_1(0)))$ in Buchholz's psi function. You can read more about it here: [https://googology.fandom.com/wiki/Cantor's_ordinal](https://googology.fandom.com/wiki/Cantor%27s_ordinal)

If by $\omega_\mu$ you mean the enumeration of infinite cardinals, then the least fixed point of $\mu \mapsto \omega_\mu$ doesn't have a specific name, but it is written as $\Phi_1(0)$ using Rathjen's $\Phi$ function. The ordinal doesn't have that many specific properties, apart from $\psi_{\chi_0(0)}(\Phi_1(0))$ in [Rathjen's psi function](https://googology.fandom.com/wiki/Rathjen%27s_psi_function) being the countable limit of the extended Buchholz's psi function.

Answer (score 3):

As Noah Schweber mentioned, the Veblen function is relevant for fixed points of $\alpha\mapsto\varepsilon_\alpha$. The Veblen hierarchy starts with $\varphi_0(\alpha)=\omega^\alpha$, and each $\varphi_\beta(\alpha)$ with $\beta>0$ enumerates the simultaneous fixed points of all the functions $\varphi_\gamma$ with $\gamma<\beta$.

$\varphi_n$ for finite $n$ can be proven total by the [fixed point lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_lemma_for_normal_functions), which says for any increasing function $f:\textrm{Ord}\rightarrow\textrm{Ord}$ which commutes with suprema (i.e. $f(\textrm{sup}(A))=\textrm{sup}(f''A)$ for $A\subset\textrm{Ord}$.), there exist arbitrarily large fixed points of $f$. In particular, we can change $\varphi_0$ to any normal function and each $\varphi_n$ remains normal, so the fixed-point lemma still applies. $\alpha\mapsto\omega_\alpha$ is a normal function, if we change $\varphi_0$ to this we get [Rathjen's $\Phi_n$ functions](https://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/%7Erathjen/Ord_Notation_Weakly_Mahlo.pdf#page=3) with $n<\omega$. (To prove each function in the full $\Phi$ hierarchy is total, we need more than the fixed point lemma.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a natural way of going beyond the operations addition, multiplication, exponentiation of ordinals to higher level operations, the next being *tetration* (but not the usual notion of tetration; see below) and *hyper-tetration*, the latter being a term I made up around 1990 but probably not used online until this [4 March 2002 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/WBZ53faqft0/m/llkUkquLPA8J). In an analogous way that exponentiation is not suitable for giving explicit formulas to the terms of the transfinite sequence of $\varepsilon$-numbers, ordinal tetration is also not suitable. However, explicit formulas for these terms can be given using ordinal hyper-tetration.

In my answer to the MSE question [Why are tetrations not useful?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4300119/13130) I discussed ordinal tetration a bit. Because that MSE question was closed and thus might not be visible to everyone, I'll repeat the definition and a few relevant comments given there.

**Ordinal Tetration.** Fix an ordinal $\alpha$. We define $\, \sideset{_{}^\beta}{}\alpha \,$ by transfinite induction on $\beta$ as follows.

(*base case*) $\;\; \sideset{_{}^0}{}\alpha = 1\;$ and $\; \sideset{_{}^1}{}\alpha = \alpha$

(*successor case*) $\;\; \sideset{_{}^{\beta + 1}}{}\alpha \; = \; \left(\sideset{_{}^{\beta}}{}\alpha \right)^{\alpha} \;$ for each $\; \beta \geq 1$

(*limit case*) $\;\; \sideset{_{}^{\lambda}}{}\alpha \; = \; \sup \left\{\sideset{_{}^{\beta}}{}{\alpha}: \; \beta < \lambda \right\}\;$ if $\; \lambda \;$ is a nonzero limit ordinal

**Ordinal Tetration vs Usual Tetration.** In the case of finite ordinals (i.e. non-negative integers), this is NOT the same as the [usual tetration operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration). For instance,
$$\sideset{_{}^4}{}\alpha \; = \; \left( \sideset{_{}^3}{}{\alpha} \right)^{\alpha} \; = \; \left( \left( \sideset{_{}^2}{}{\alpha} \right)^{\alpha} \right)^{\alpha} \; = \; \left( \left( {\alpha}^{\alpha} \right)^{\alpha} \right)^{\alpha} \; = \; {\alpha}^{{\alpha}^{3}} $$
In fact, it can be shown that ("top-down" evaluations are used here)
$$\sideset{_{}^{\epsilon_0}}{}{\epsilon_0} \; = \; {\epsilon_0}^{{\epsilon_0}^{\epsilon_0}} $$
Moreover, we also have $\; \epsilon_0 \; = \; \sup\left\{\omega, \; \sideset{_{}^{\omega}}{}{\omega}, \; \sideset{_{}^{\sideset{_{}^{\omega}}{}{\omega}}}{}{\omega}, \; \ldots \right\}$, and hence it follows that
$$ \epsilon_0 \; = \; {\omega}^{{\omega}^{{\omega}^{{\cdot}^{{\cdot}^{\cdot}}}}} \; = \; \sideset{_{}^{\sideset{_{}^{\sideset{_{}^{\sideset{_{}^{\sideset{_{}^{\cdot}}{}{\cdot}}}{}{\cdot}}}{}{\omega}}}{}{\omega}}}{}{\omega} $$
(In the above, each ellipsis signifies the supremum of all finite-iterated exponentiation/tetration expressions evaluated "top-down".)

**Strong Tetration and Weak Tetration.** There does not seem to be a standard term for this distinction in the literature, probably because this distinction does not arise very often. Mark Neyrinck’s May 1995 undergraduate thesis [**An Investigation of Arithmetic Operations**](http://skysrv.pha.jhu.edu/%7Eneyrinck/extessay.pdf) uses the term *top-down* and *bottom-up*. I propose, when these two types of tetration are being discussed together for natural numbers, to use the term *strong tetration* for the ordinary notion of tetration and the term *weak tetration* for the ordinal notion of tetration as defined above.

We now consider the next higher level operation (not mentioned in that MSE answer), which I'll call "hyper-tetration". This is also defined in a "bottom-up" manner.

**Ordinal Hyper-Tetration.** Fix an ordinal $\alpha$. We define $\, \sideset{_{}^{\{\beta\}}}{}\alpha \,$ by transfinite induction on $\beta$ as follows.

(*base case*) $\;\; \sideset{_{}^{\{0\}}}{}\alpha = 1\;$ and $\;\sideset{_{}^{\{1\}}}{}\alpha = \alpha$

(*successor case*) $\;\; \sideset{_{}^{\{{\beta + 1\}}}}{}\alpha \; = \; \sideset{_{}^{\alpha}}{}{\left(\sideset{_{}^{\{\beta\}}}{}\alpha \right)} \;$ for each $\; \beta \geq 1$

(*limit case*) $\;\; \sideset{_{}^{\{\lambda \}}}{}\alpha \; = \; \sup \left\{\sideset{_{}^{\{\beta \}}}{}{\alpha}: \; \beta < \lambda \right\}\;$ if $\lambda$ is a nonzero limit ordinal

The following results are proved in some personal notes of mine that I first wrote around 1990, and which I have revised several times since then:

**Let** $\;\alpha \geq 2.\;$ **The least** $\varepsilon$**-number greater than** $\; \alpha \;$ **is** $\; \sideset{_{}^{\{\omega\}}}{}\alpha.$

**Explicit Expressions for** $\varepsilon$**-Numbers Using Hyper-Tetration:**

**1.** $\;$Let $\;0 \leq n < \omega.\;$ Then $\;\varepsilon_n \; = \;\sideset{_{}^{\{\omega \cdot (n+1)\}}}{}{\omega}.$ 
**2.** $\;$Let $\;\beta \geq \omega.\;$ Then $\;{\varepsilon}_{\beta} \; = \; \sideset{_{}^{\{\omega \cdot \beta\}}}{}{\omega}.$

These two formulas can be replaced with the single formula $\;{\varepsilon}_{\beta} \; = \; \sideset{_{}^{\{\omega \cdot (1 + \beta)\}}}{}{\omega},\;$ which holds for all ordinals $\beta.$

These results and much more -- formulas for the transfinite sequence of fixed points of $\alpha$'th level operations on ordinal numbers (where $\alpha$ is any finite or transfinite ordinal) -- can be found in [*An extended arithmetic of ordinal numbers*](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm65/fm65110.pdf) by Doner and Tarski (1969; [another copy](https://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Edoner/articles/Doner-Tarski.pdf)), along with an explanation of why the "bottom-up" formulations for the operations are used (see the first full paragraph on p. 113).

Comment: Regarding the discussion above about strong and weak tetration, see also the comments to [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/112103/15780), in particular the up arrow and down arrow operations, which I apparently wasn't aware of until now (or more likely, I had seen it earlier and forgotten about it).

Comment: In case the link I gave to Mark Neyrinck’s May 1995 undergraduate thesis **An Investigation of Arithmetic Operations** goes dead, I've saved it at the Internet Archive [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20230814040745/http://skysrv.pha.jhu.edu/~neyrinck/extessay.pdf). To keep from bumping my answer to the top of the queue, I'm putting this new link in a comment. However, if at some later time I happen to notice that my original link is dead, then I'll incorporate the Internet Archive link into the main body of my answer.